# MATLAB - Index exceeds matrix dimensions when writing to text file

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, dimensions

uData is 27x5 matrix containing numbers. 1 column each is taken by ID, scE, ccE, scC, and ccC (please see below code).

name_Database is a 27x1 cell array containing names in the form of strings.

I am getting the error

Index exceeds matrix dimensions. 
Where am I going wrong? Input here would be greatly appreciated.

```
% Header 'Name', 'ID', 'scE', 'ccE', 'scC', 'ccC'
ID = dbedit.uData(:,1);
scE = dbedit.uData(:,2);
ccE = dbedit.uData(:,3);
scC = dbedit.uData(:,4);
ccC = dbedit.uData(:,5);
names = dbedit.name_Database;

% Create array versions to account for proper spacing 
% within the text file. 
ID_cell = cellstr(num2str(ID.'));
scE_cell = cellstr(num2str(scE.'));
ccE_cell = cellstr(num2str(ccE.'));
scC_cell = cellstr(num2str(scC.'));
ccC_cell = cellstr(num2str(ccC.'));
output_file = 'uDatabase.txt'; % Text file to output data into.
fid = fopen(output_file, 'w+'); %// open file for writing

fprintf(fid, 'Name\t ID\t scE\t ccE\t scC\t ccC\n'); % Header

for ii=1:numel(names)
fprintf(fid, '%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\n',names{ii},...
ID_cell{ii},scE_cell{ii},ccE_cell{ii},scC_cell{ii},...
ccC_cell{ii}); %// write data
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: The error message will tell you on what line it occurs. On that line you will be referencing an element or elements of an array that do not exist, because they are bigger than the size of the array. Matlab error messages are (usually) **very** useful. Read them careful and fully and then look where the error occurs, and you should be able to fix most things like this yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, it plainly says "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" and there are no more lines or any specific indicators to certain lines.

Comment: OK, the next step to debug is to work out where the error is. Work it out, and let us know which line causes the problem.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: The "stop on error" feature of the debugger is incredibly useful, as you can then directly inspect the program state at the exact point it goes wrong.